# getting Bitmap From Asset

Tags: java, android, bitmap, adb, apk

I have probelm getting  Bitmap From Assets

I tried running my app in debug mode, when I click play (call image saved in assets folder) the app stops working and the debugger gives me these breakpoints

```
SceneActivity [line: 536] - onCreate(Bundle)    
SceneActivity [line: 763] - getBitmapFromAsset(String)  
SceneActivity [line: 792] - createObjectResizerManager()    
SceneActivity [line: 796] - createObjectResizerManager()
```

and these stacks

```
Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (breakpoint at line 763 in SceneActivity)) 
<VM does not provide monitor information>   
SceneActivity.getBitmapFromAsset(String) line: 763  
SceneActivity.onCreate(Bundle) line: 468    
SceneActivity(Activity).performCreate(Bundle) line: 5104    
Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Activity, Bundle) line: 1080   
ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 2144    
ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 2230 
ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread, ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 141    
ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(Message) line: 1234  
ActivityThread$H(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 99 
Looper.loop() line: 137 
ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 5041    
Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 511  
ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 793  
ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 560 
NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]
```

this is my code

```
    /**
 * Retrieves Bitmap from Asset
 * @param strName
 * @return
 * @throws IOException
 */
    private Bitmap getBitmapFromAsset(String strName) throws IOException {
        AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
        InputStream istr = assetManager.open(strName);
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(istr);
        istr.close();
        return bitmap;
    }
/**
```

note: the app was working fine until I tried exporting it as APK, this involved me doing some updates in SDK "installed sdk build tool 20" to fix a problem with proguard "can't find referenced class org.w3c.dom.bootstrap.DOMImplementationRegistry"

Comment: What is the error? You only posted the stacktrace to your breakpoint.

Comment: try moving it to drawables folder

Comment: sorry I wasn't clear, there is no error, it just terminates the app and give me these stacks, and it selects this line  "AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();" in SceneActivity java file

Comment: and these are the break points

SceneActivity [line: 536] - onCreate(Bundle) 
SceneActivity [line: 763] - getBitmapFromAsset(String) 
SceneActivity [line: 792] - createObjectResizerManager() 
SceneActivity [line: 796] - createObjectResizerManager()

Comment: What happens if you do not run your app in debug mode?

Comment: I exported it and tried running it with bluestack, it didn't work, doesn't show anything

Comment: I run it as android application and it worked without a problem, the problem is when I export it it doesn't work at all